# SPEC 2006 benchmarking alternative for ARM devices with limited RAM

Tags: arm, benchmarking, performance-testing

Is there any alternative benchmarking to SPEC 2006 for ARM devices with limited memory. Unfortunately, SPEC 2006 needs 1GB ram for 32bit platform and 2GB for 64bit devices (without considering OS requirement for RAM,so your RAM must be even more than that).

Unfortunately, my test platform is an ARM v8 (64bit) with 256 MB of RAM. I am looking for alternatives for SPEC 2006 in my system. Is there any?

Comment: You do understand benchmarking yes?  Just variations in the compiler, adding a nop or few in the bootstrap, etc.  Other than alignment adjustments the same source code performance can vary on the same hardware in the tens of a percent difference.  Change the compiler on the same hardware and you can see more than tens of a percent difference.  This includes all the features of the benchmark as well...Just saying...take it with a grain of salt.  At the end of the day how fast it runs YOUR application is all that matters.

Comment: SPEC is a standard suite of representative tests designed to benchmark two things - the system hardware that's running them, and the compiler that built them - but then you're talking about benchmarking your own program. I don't see how these two things are supposed to fit together...

Comment: SPECcpu doesn't measure "CPU overhead", it measures total wall-clock time.  Most of the time is not overhead, it's time the CPU actually spends running the benchmark.  See for example [the results submitted so far in 2016Q3](https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/results/res2016q3/), or the details of the submission for a [Dell dual-socket Broadwell Xeon system (2x14 cores @ 2.6GHz)](https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/results/res2016q3/cpu2006-20160628-42605.html).  The numbers are how fast it is relative to the 296 MHz UltraSPARC II reference machine: **https://www.spec.org/cpu2006/Docs/readme1st.html**

Comment: Unless your application is _one of the SPEC tests_ (which I rather doubt), I don't think you understand how this works. The paper you refer to is effectively using SPEC to test _compiler_ changes (albeit by post-processing the compiled binaries), not some random third-party application. Maybe you could hack up the SPEC test harness to run you own application instead, I don't know, but that would make the memory requirements of SPEC's own test programs irrelevant anyway. Coremark, similarly, will be running _its own_ standard test code for comparable measurements across different CPUs...

Comment: I do not know why I do not see an answer. Assuming I am wrong about spec, does not change the question. Is there SPEC alternative for ARM based devices with limited memory?

Comment: software recommendations are technically off-topic.  IDK how other people feel about asking for benchmark recommendations.  The biggest problem is that you haven't told us anything about what kind of thing you want your benchmark to measure.  Integer or FP?  More like gcc or more like gzip?  Or are you implying that you want to measure the same mix of things as SPECint / SPECfp, but with smaller problem sizes?

Comment: @PeterCordes I want to modify an application and compare my modification with original application to understand the impact of my modification on the program. Application can be compiled with GCC.

Comment: @SamaAzari:  If you still want to measure the impact of changes to your own applications, why did you edit your question to have NOTHING to do with that?  The question now is asking for some kind of standard benchmark suite which can run on a low-memory ARM.

Comment: Unless your applications is one that slows down or speeds up *other* applications by rewriting their code or something (like the paper you linked), SPEC isn't going to help you benchmark it.

Comment: @PeterCordes My application exactly is doing what you described thats why I need it for my platform.

Comment: You should have clearly said that sooner, because that's really uncommon.  I think everyone was completely correct in assuming you were confused based on what you posted until this last comment.  So it's the quality of the results of your app that you want to measure, NOT the execution speed of your application's own code.

Comment: Does a non-parallel execution of SPECint really take that much RAM?  I would have guessed that it only gets bad if you do SPECint_rate / SPECfp_rate, where you measure the throughput of several parallel runs of SPEC.  One instance of gcc doesn't usually take huge amount of memory.